# How to Select polygons within a feature based on rules applied to FID

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select-by-attribute

I want to select all the polygons of a vector grid which have a FID multiple of N (e.g. N=5). Is that possible?

Comment: Have you looked into using a modulus operator?

Comment: Fid in (5,10,15)  unless you'd like to compute additional field as @PolyGeo suggested

Comment: FID is an internal identifier, not well-suited for use in this manner. The range of values and ordering can vary by data format, and deleted features' IDs may or may not be reassigned. I would recommend extreme caution in the use of this methodology.

Comment: @Vince I agree that is maybe better to add a new field and calculate it as =FID or =FID+1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Select by Attributes and enter

```
MOD(FID, 5) = 0
```

Where `FID` is the fieldname and `5` is the multiple you want to select by.

It may need to be `"FID"` or `[FID]`

[image]

Comment: This won't work in select by attribute window

Comment: @FelixIP screenshot added showing use of Select by Attributes window and result in attribute table

Comment: +1. My bad, memory games I tried this on 9.3, didn't work